# Inserting local image into *Wakari* IPython notebook

Tags: python, image, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a Wakari (IPython 1.0 notebook) university course, currently I'm converting my lecture materials into interactive notebooks containing text, static images and python code. However, I've not managed so far to include local (to the Wakari filesystem) images in my notebooks with a nice layout:

Including remote images via HTML

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Double-compound-pendulum-dimensioned.svg">
```

or Markdown

```
![caption](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Double-compound-pendulum-dimensioned.svg)
```

works fine, as well as using python code

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename=('/user_home/w_Chipmuenk/DSV/Linearized_Quantizer.png'))
```

but the Python cell gives an ugly break in the text.

What I'd like to do instead is something like

```
<img src="files/user_home/w_Chipmuenk/DSV/Linearized_Quantizer.png">
<img src="files/DSV/Linearized_Quantizer.png">
<img src="files/Linearized_Quantizer.png">
```

Unfortunately, none of the combinations above works for me (and I've tried plenty others as well ...) Is this a Wakari specific problem or am I doing something wrong?

Cheers,

Christian

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in Wakari and it worked fine.

1. I created a folder called `~/images`
2. I uploaded my image `roms_vectors.png` to the `~/images` folder
3. I created a markdown cell with this single line:

```
![my image](files/images/roms_vectors.png)
```